# allowableMovement seems to be ignored

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uigesturerecognizer

The `allowableMovement` property in my `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` seems to be ignored. I created a new project (Xcode 4.5.1, iOS 6) using the Single View Application template and added a Long Press Gesture Recognizer to the view. There's an outlet wired up and an action. Here's the code for the action method:

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender
{    
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible)   NSLog(@"possible");
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)      NSLog(@"began");
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)    NSLog(@"changed");    
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized) NSLog(@"recognized");    
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled)  NSLog(@"cancelled");
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)     NSLog(@"failed");

    CGPoint locationInView = [sender locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"long press: allowableMovement= %f, x= %f, y= %f", sender.allowableMovement, locationInView.x, locationInView.y);
}
```

If I press long enough and let go I get this in the log:

```
2012-10-30 20:24:41.449 Long Press[1078:907] began
2012-10-30 20:24:41.455 Long Press[1078:907] long press: allowableMovement= 10.000000, x= 210.500000, y= 99.500000
2012-10-30 20:24:42.880 Long Press[1078:907] recognized
2012-10-30 20:24:42.882 Long Press[1078:907] long press: allowableMovement= 10.000000, x= 208.500000, y= 96.000000
```

This is what I would expect.

But no matter what I set `allowableMovement` to (positive, negative, big, small), once the state is `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan`, I can drag my finger all over the screen. The state changes to `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and there are frequent updates and locationInView continues to accurately track. When I let go I get the `UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized` state and a final output to the log.

The class reference says that the recognizer should fail if movement exceeds `allowableMovement`. Why does the `allowableMovement` property seem to be ignored?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `allowableMovement` property is not about how far you can drag after the gesture has started. It is about how far you can move before the gesture starts.

From the class reference:

> The gesture begins (UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) when the number of allowable fingers (numberOfTouchesRequired) have been pressed for the specified period (minimumPressDuration) and the touches do not move beyond the allowable range of movement (allowableMovement).

This becomes apparent when you set `minimumPressDuration` to something high like 3 seconds and `allowableMovement` to something low like 1 pixel. If your finger rolls at all the gesture won't begin. But if you set `allowableMovement` to 100 your finger can roll around quite a bit and the gesture will start.

In this way it is like the other properties. They are all about what is required for the gesture to start.

Comment: @ Murray Sagal: This solved my confusion too. Wondering, if there is a way to detect if the user drags their finger out of the view after LongPressGesture begins.

Comment: @TPos I think you can use `locationInView:` or one of the methods like it. But it sounds like it would be worthy of its own question.

Answer (score 6):

I thought `allowableMovement` had exactly that purpose. I made a small subclass to implement the "expected" behavior with a `allowableMovementAfterBegan`.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>

@interface TDMLongPressGestureRecognizer : UILongPressGestureRecognizer
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat allowableMovementAfterBegan;
@end

@implementation TDMLongPressGestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint initialPoint;
}

- (instancetype)initWithTarget:(id)target action:(SEL)action
{
    self = [super initWithTarget:target action:action];
    if (self) {
        // Use default value for allowableMovement before touches begin
        _allowableMovementAfterBegan = self.allowableMovement; 
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)reset
{
    [super reset];      
    initialPoint = CGPointZero;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];   
    initialPoint = [self locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(initialPoint, CGPointZero))
    {
        CGPoint currentPoint = [self locationInView:self.view];

        CGFloat distance = hypot(initialPoint.x - currentPoint.x, initialPoint.y - currentPoint.y);
        if (distance > self.allowableMovementAfterBegan)
            self.state = UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. What's your use case for limiting the allowable movement?

Comment: I've used it for long-pressing on contents in a UIScrollView.

Comment: Just ran into the case you're referring to - have a UICollectionViewCell that i'd like to add a gesture recognizer to, but cancel the gesture if the user scrolls the UICollectionView vertically (this is how UITableView works by default). It was also surprising to me that allowableMovement didn't mean that as well, but this seems like a great solution so thanks!

Comment: @duemunk When you set the state to `Failed`, is the scrollview the gesture is in then able to scroll? I have not been able to achieve this.

Comment: @JonahKatz Do you use it on the scrollview? I've used for subviews to a scrollview.

Comment: @duemunk Yeah, subviews. Ended getting it to work. UIGestures have a delegate method `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` which allows the scrollView and the gesture to work with the touch event